# Configuring Answer To Recently Edited Post

Tags: support, answers, etiquette

There was an answer on this post: [Applying different CSS class on click using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9182360/applying-different-css-class-on-click-using-jquery) that related to the old question **before** I edited the question.

It has a couple of up-votes and it seems I know from [this FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21788/how-does-editing-work) I can't do anything to edit the answer, since the original author has that capability. I want people to understand that the answer in this particular post doesn't at all answer my question.

Is there a way I can notify someone this is the wrong answer and remove it? Or is there another alternative, like being able to vote down the question and having it removed that way, similar to this: [Marking answer as 'not the answer'](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73665/marking-answer-as-not-the-answer)?

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Solution: don't edit your questions to make existing answers incorrect after they've been posted. Especially not 10 months later. FWIW, the community can suggest edits to answers.

Comment: @Wooble I will definitely remember that for next time. I guess I thought there was some easy way to be able to get rid of the irrelevant answers.

Comment: If it's your question, you can comment on any answer even with low rep. Leave a comment saying that the answer isn't right for the revised question. Alternately, rollback your question edit and ask a fresh question.

Comment: @KateGregory I've never heard of rolling back on a question edit. What and how do you do this?

Comment: Click on the "edited by" link and you can change an edit back. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17038/what-is-a-rollback for more details.

Comment: @KateGregory Wooble if you look at the question's edit history, rolling back is almost certainly not a good idea in this instance.

Comment: @KateGregory Okay, in this case, this isn't the best scenario. Thank you for the reply though.