# Can we show status of user?

Tags: feature-request, users

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Is there a way to identify whether users are online or not?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4445/is-there-a-way-to-identify-whether-users-are-online-or-not)
>   [Online/offline or Away status indicator in Stack overflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67143/online-offline-or-away-status-indicator-in-stack-overflow)

Can we show status of user in his signature/profile so that we can understand whether he is Online or Offline?? 
If it is not already implemented can you provide this feature?

Comment: See: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4445/is-there-a-way-to-identify-whether-users-are-online-or-not or http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67143/online-offline-or-away-status-indicator-in-stack-overflow

Comment: Vote down hurts but i checked the already posted questions suggested to me. anyways thanks for the answers that helped.

Comment: My guess is that someone downvoted because they didn't agree that this would be useful - on Meta Stack Overflow, votes on a feature request indicate support for it. I'm sure the downvote is probably for that, not for having posted a duplicate.

Comment: Votedown in meta means whether your feature request will be considered or not. So dont worry about downvotes in meta. btw, i did not downvote you... ;)

Comment: @Grace. Yeah Ill keep it in mind. thanks.. @Sachin :)

Answer (score 5):

You can already tell (approximately) when they were last seen on the site by viewing their profile.

[image: Seen]

These sites are more about the questions and answers than about individual users, so I don't think we need this indicator in the signature link.

Comment: thats true but sometimes user helping you stops replying ur answer and then you start wondering if he/she is online or not.

Answer (score 2):

There is already such feature. If you go to User profile, there is a property "SEEN". This shows the minutes passed after the user was last seen.

If the minutes is within 10 or 15, generally the user is still online.

***IGNORE*** the below answer based on comment from Grace -

*According to my observation, there is one more way too. If user has an accept rate, then the accept rate is shown in green if he is online, else it is shown in grey. Not sure if this is really true or not.*

Comment: Just to teach you, the last part is not true. It's shown in green if it's a relatively high number, and grey if it's around the 50% area. It goes to deep red as you approach 0%.

Comment: @Grace - Ok, thanks for confirming. Editing my answer accordingly.

Comment: There is an unanswered question on what the colours of the accept rate mean - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/68703/what-do-the-different-colours-of-accept-rate-mean